# Calculating Year to Date Total

Tags: sql-server

I want to generate a Payroll type query whereby the values in Payroll 1 (say for the previous month) should be included in Payroll 2 (for the current month) Year-to-Date Totals.

This can best be explained with an example:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, PayrollID INT, Description NVARCHAR(MAX), [Current Month] MONEY)

INSERT INTO @MyTable
VALUES  (1,'Basic Salary',100),
        (1,'Normal Over Time',50),
        (1,'Work on Saturday',150),
        (1,'Work on Sunday',200),

        (2,'Basic Salary',100)

SELECT * ,SUM([Current Month]) OVER (PARTITION BY  Description ORDER BY PayrollID) AS [Month to Date]
FROM @MyTable
```

When I run the above I get

```
ID  EmployeeID  PayrollID   Description     Current Month   Month to Date
1      1           1        Basic Salary        100             100
2      1           1        Normal Over Time     50              50
3      1           1        Work on Saturday    150             150
4      1           1        Work on Sunday      200             200
5      1           2        Basic Salary        100             200
```

The Year-to-Date running totals are per each Description meaning Basic Salary Category has its own running total and so does Saturday and Sunday etc, etc. You will notice that for Basic Salary in Payroll 2 the running Year-to-Date total is 200 (i.e. 100 from Payroll 1 + 100 from Payroll 2)

The challenge I have is that Payroll 1 has data for Basic Salary, Work on Saturday and Work on Sunday whereas Payroll 2 only has Basic Salary as the employee did not work on Saturday nor on Sunday in Payroll 2 (the current month).

However, in the cumulative Year-to-Date column the data from Payroll 1 (previous month) should still be selected and included in the Year-to-Date running Total - 
something like this:

```
ID  EmployeeID  PayrollID   Description     Current Month   Month to Date
1      1           1        Basic Salary         100            100
2      1           1        Normal Over Time      50             50
3      1           1        Work on Saturday     150            150
4      1           1        Work on Sunday       200            200
5      1           2        Basic Salary         100            200
2      1           1        Normal Over Time     NULL            50
3      1           1        Work on Saturday     NULL           150
4      1           1        Work on Sunday       NULL           200
```

Although the employee did not work on Saturday nor Sunday in the current month (Payroll 2) the running (Year-to-Date) totals for working on a Saturday should be 150 that he/she worked in the previous month (Payroll 1). The same should apply to working on Sunday where the running total in the current month (Payroll 2) should be the 200 that he/she worked in the previous month (Payroll 1).

How do I do that with a simple Select Statement without writing a complicated Procedure?

**EDIT:**

I have cleaned up the ode as follows:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, EmployeeID INT, PayrollID INT, Description NVARCHAR(MAX), [Current Month] MONEY)

INSERT INTO @MyTable
VALUES  (1,1,'Basic Salary',100),
        (1,1,'Normal Over Time',50),
        (1,1,'Work on Saturday',150),
        (1,1,'Work on Sunday',200),

        (1,2,'Basic Salary',100)
WITH pay_elements AS
(
    SELECT Description
    FROM @MyTable
    GROUP BY Description
)

,pay_slips AS
(
    SELECT EmployeeID, PayrollID
    FROM @MyTable
    GROUP BY EmployeeID, PayrollID
)
,pay_lines AS
(
    SELECT
        mt.ID
        ,PS.EmployeeID
        ,PS.PayrollID
        ,PE.Description
        ,ISNULL(mt.[Current Month], 0) AS [Current Month]

    FROM
        pay_slips AS ps

    OUTER APPLY
        pay_elements AS pe

    LEFT JOIN
        @MyTable AS mt
        ON (mt.EmployeeID = ps.EmployeeID)
        AND (mt.PayrollID = ps.PayrollID)
        AND (mt.Description = pe.Description)
)

SELECT * ,SUM([Current Month]) OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeID, Description ORDER BY PayrollID) AS [Month to Date]
FROM pay_lines
```

And I get this error:

```
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 23
Incorrect syntax near ','.
```

Comment: Good show man. Thanks a billion times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to build a "structure" of row headings, and then join that onto the actual data.

So for example:

```
WITH pay_elements AS
(
    SELECT Description
    FROM @MyTable
    GROUP BY Description
)
,pay_slips AS
(
    SELECT EmployeeID, PayrollID
    FROM @MyTable
    GROUP BY EmployeeID, PayrollID
)
,pay_lines AS
(
    SELECT
        mt.ID
        ,pay_slips.EmployeeID
        ,pay_slips.PayrollID
        ,pay_elements.Description
        ,ISNULL(mt.Current_Month, 0) AS Current_Month

    FROM
        pay_slips AS ps

    OUTER APPLY
        pay_elements AS pe

    LEFT JOIN
        @MyTable AS mt
        ON (mt.EmployeeID = ps.EmployeeID)
        AND (mt.PayrollID = ps.PayrollID)
        AND (mt.Description = pe.Description)
)

SELECT * ,SUM([Current Month]) OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeID, Description ORDER BY PayrollID) AS [Month to Date]
FROM pay_lines
```

What we're doing here is getting a list of the different kind of pay elements in your table. Then we're getting a list of Employees and Payrolls done to date, and manually forcing every Payroll to include a row in respect of all possible pay elements.

Once that structure is built, we join onto the base table to get the actual values (replacing NULLs with zeros, for those pay elements that weren't originally included in the base table).

Then we simply query this padded-out table in the same way you did originally.

Note, I've written this on the fly and haven't checked this code so please excuse any minor errors.

Comment: @Edgar, I've just seen your proposed edit to my post with an additional question. Follow-up questions are asked via an edit to your post and not mine - so I've transferred the edit to your post. The error you are getting means that you need to put a semicolon on the line before the WITH clause - after the end of the INSERT INTO statement.

Answer (score 0):

I am little confused with the column you mentioned Year-to-Date in your description. I assume this might be `[Month to Date]` column present in your query. Please correct me if I am wrong.

I think what you are trying to achieve is - the descriptions which are not present in payroll ID 2 like Work on Saturday and Work on Sunday should also be selected below the result set.

Problem is:

> Summation of NULL value is always NULL so if [Current Month] value is NULL then you can not achieve to display 50,150,200 in the [Month to Date] column

You can have fixed categories against each payroll id:

- Normal Over Time
- Work on Saturday
- Work on Sunday
- Basic Salary

**Query**:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, PayrollID INT, Description NVARCHAR(MAX), [Current Month] MONEY)

INSERT INTO @MyTable
VALUES  (1,'Basic Salary',100),
        (1,'Normal Over Time',50),
        (1,'Work on Saturday',150),
        (1,'Work on Sunday',200),
        (2,'Basic Salary',100),
        (2,'Normal Over Time',0),
    (2,'Work on Saturday',0),
    (2,'Work on Sunday',0)


SELECT * ,SUM([Current Month]) OVER (PARTITION BY  Description ORDER BY PayrollID) AS [Month to Date]
FROM @MyTable order by ID,PayrollID
```